# excel: Look up value within cell from list of values in other range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, keyword

I have a list of long tail keywords (phrases) and I have a separate list of negative keywords. I would like to look up which phrases contain any of the negative keywords in the other list.

Vlookup will not work for this as it is only an exact match. I've also tried playing with the search and find function but could not figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Sean

Comment: please give us sample data and expected result. Thanks.

Comment: This may be useful to you https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php

Comment: I've figured this out! I used an Excel add on by Microsoft called Fuzzy Lookup and it's awesome! thanks for all your suggestions :)